# How can I turn off unicorn only for particular URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I'm using Rails 3.2 + nginx + unicorn.
My rails app is working fine as well.
I'm facing a problem now since I switched to nginx from Apache.

For particular URL, I want to disable unicorn, and make it access directly to the target PHP page.

I used to disable passenger when the user accesses to `foo-sample.com/phpmyadmin`, which is PHP based.

How can I modify my current conf file?

**etc/nginx/conf.d/rails.conf** <= What should I add to this?

```
upstream sample {
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn/unicorn_foo-sample.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo-sample.com;
    root /var/www/html/foo-sample/public;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://sample;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets|system/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

When I was using passenger, I was setting up conf file just like these.

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foo-sample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/foo-sample/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/foo-sample/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>  

    <Location /phpmyadmin>
        PassengerEnabled off
   </Location>   

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf**

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/"
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/"

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/" >

   AllowOverride all

</Directory>
```

**Trial**

```
.
.
.
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/your/php-fpm/socket;
    }
}
.
.
.
```

With this code, if I access to `foo-sample.com/phpmyadmin`, it let me access to `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/index.php`. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Try refactoring your rails.conf in such way:

```
upstream sample {
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn/unicorn_foo-sample.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo-sample.com;
    root /var/www/html/foo-sample/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php $uri/index.html @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://sample;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets|system/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
        index index.php;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(/.+\.php)$ {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin$1;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/your/php-fpm/socket;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you should use Nginx [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive. In this particular example it will try to process static and PHP files first. If there are no such files - request will be passed to Unicorn backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) What comes within `# add code which enables PHP backend`?

Comment: and what if target page doesn't show extention? something like `foo-sample.com/phpmyadmin` not `foo-sample.com/phpmyadmin/index.php`

Comment: Check modified answer :)

Comment: Thanks for modification. I tried your code but it returns `404 Not Found` Indeed, I have `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` this is so weird

Comment: For the cases when target path doesn't contain extention we have values `$uri/index.php` and `$uri/index.html` in `try_files` directive. If user enters `http://foo-sample.com/phpmyadmin` - it will try to math routes in such order: `/root/path/phpmyadmin` - not a file, `/root/path/phpmyadmin/index.php` - found

Comment: Thanks. I added my trial code to my original question. So please see it. But it still returns 404 error:(

Comment: **access.log** `"GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2" "-"`

Comment: **error.log** ` [error] 2748#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/phpmyadmin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1"`

Comment: Can you help me out little bit more? I think you are getting way close to it!

Comment: Sure, I guess there is an issue with phpmyadmin root path declaration.

Comment: Thanks. What part should I modify?

Comment: Thanks!! Now **error.log** returns this `[crit] 3640#0: *1 connect() to unix:/path/to/your/php-fpm/socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/path/to/your/php-fpm/socket:"
`

Comment: You need to specify your **real** path to php-fpm socket (unix or http). I just specified an example, not the real path.
More info about nginx proxy_path derective [described here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass).

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that I had to set up php-fpm:( I thought I don't need to install any once I installed php and nginx. Thanks!